# Xamarin iOS GUI

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We've been developing a cross-platform app in Xamarin on Windows and now we are moving to make GUI for iOS counterpart.

If I'm understanding correctly we need to switch to Visual Studio for MAC, on a MAC machine, and continue our GUI development there.
Is it possible to develop everything on Windows and *just* publish an app on the MAC machine?
How do we include the logic and everything from the android app?

Comment: The process and options for doing this are really well documented.  Have you taken the time to read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows

Comment: Since we do not have access to the Mac machine we cannot pair to Mac we have a VirtualBox virtual machine up and running (I know about the (il)legality of it all). 
So there is no other way of doing it than that?

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin Hi, If you do not have access to a Mac, you can use MacinCloud or MacStadium; both services provide cloud-based Mac hardware that you can use to build Xamarin.iOS projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xamarin.Forms to develop UI for both Android and iOS.

But if its already native then you can still continue developing it in Windows.
For the build and testing you definitely need a MAC, if you don't want to use a VM then you can build it on the cloud using a https://www.macincloud.com/ or other party that uses the same service, and use a simulator on windows.

If its cross platform then I assume you're using a .NET Standard for the shared codebase. So there would be no problem using the same logic for both the Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you. Many apps will work by just publishing on the Mac. Of those many will have some artifacts that shouldn't be in the end version.

To simplify it is like asking whether you should publish the app without testing and fixing. In 99% no, but sometimes it may work.